# R: the line function is not producing a line

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I am trying to add a density curve to my histogram.

Here is my code:

```
    privateCollege <- data.frame(filter(college.df, Private == "Yes"))
    publicCollege <- data.frame(filter(college.df, Private == "No"))
    hist(privateCollege$PhD, main = "PhD holder in Private Colleges")
    hist(publicCollege$PhD, main = "PhD holder in Public Colleges")
    line(density(privateCollege$PhD, adjust = 2))
```

I am expecting the last line of my code giving me the density curve on the histogram "PhD holder in Private Colleges", but here is what I got:

```
    Call:
    line(density(privateCollege$PhD, adjust = 2))

    Coefficients:
    [1]  9.124e-04  5.808e-05
```

I got my histograms correct but not the density curve. Is there anyone can help me out please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try setting freq=FALSE in your histogram creation, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169061/why-is-my-density-plot-just-a-line-on-the-bottom

Comment: Welcome. To ask a question, you should give a reproducible example, i.e. give a dataset, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me out!

Comment: @KevinChan if the answer was good, why not give it an upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite probably that R by default plots a count/ frequency histogram, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169061/why-is-my-density-plot-just-a-line-on-the-bottom, so you need to set `freq=FALSE` in your `hist` call, i.e.:

```
    privateCollege <- data.frame(filter(college.df, Private == "Yes"))
    publicCollege <- data.frame(filter(college.df, Private == "No"))
    hist(privateCollege$PhD, main = "PhD holder in Private Colleges", freq=FALSE)
    hist(publicCollege$PhD, main = "PhD holder in Public Colleges", freq=FALSE)
    lines(density(privateCollege$PhD, adjust = 2))
```

See also https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html

**EDIT:**
Besides needing to set `freq=FALSE`, you also have a typo in your code, you need to use the function `lines`, ideally with the option `type="l"`